# Ews, get public subfolders where emails have been added within a given period

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Is there a way - by using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices in C# or Exchange Management Shell- to get a list of all subfolders within a Public folder, where emails have been added within a given period of time?

Thanks in advance

Shungite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EWS you can check the PidTagLocalCommitTimeMax https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663242(v=exchg.80).aspx on each folder you want to evaluate which should contain the time of the last change to the folder. The other easy way to do this and probably more accurate with public folder is just enumerate the last Item in each folder and check the date-time. Whatever method you want to use will require a separate operation on each folder you want to check.

With the EMS you can use Get-PublicFolderStatistics https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997949(v=exchg.150).aspx which has LastModification and AccessTime as well as the ability to report on Items. This will generally be quicker then EWS and not subject to permission issues.

Comment: Thank You Glen :o) I'll try it out

Comment: Hi Glen. I found a Power-shell-script here https://github.com/gscales/Powershell-Scripts/blob/master/PublicFolderMod.ps1   Did You make this? It seems to able to the trick. However, I am very new at Power-shell, so I do not know how to run this. If You made it, could You please tell me how to run it?

Comment: You need to import the module use

import-module ./PublicFolderMod.ps1

The run Enum-PublicFolders -MailboxName mailbox@domain.com

Where the MailboxName is an Admin account that has rights to all the public folders you want to report on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.